# Heroku ruby app - run gulp build process after deploy

Tags: ruby, heroku, deployment, npm, sinatra

I have a ruby application hosted on Heroku, it's a Ruby Sinatra app and I am using gulp to build my sass and coffee files for the client. I have added a postinstall script to my package.json and I have all my gulp dependencies listed but no npm install happens, probably because the app is a ruby application and npm is not on the deploy radar? Here's what my package.json looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-coffee": "^2.3.3",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm install && gulp build"
  }
```

What am I missing? Is it not possible to run npm and ruby on the same container?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

What I needed was to add a nodejs buildpack so that npm install would happen along with the postinstall script. Add a node buildpack using the Heroku CLI like this:

`heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs`

I also removed `npm install` from my postinstall hook because it happens automatically with the node buildpack.